# Passing on an argument from a wrapper to an inner function when argument is allowed to be missing in inner function - possible?

Tags: r

I have a function which has the argument `arg` which is allowed to be missing. If it is missing it is assigned some value within `foo`.

```
foo <- function(x, arg) {
  if (missing(arg))
    arg <- TRUE
  arg
}
```

I want to write a wrapper that calls `foo` for several elements of a list using `sapply` or `lapply`. And I want to pass on the `arg` argument as follows.

```
foo_wrapper <- function(x, arg) {
  sapply(x, foo, arg=arg)
}
```

This will throw an error as `arg` is not found when it is evaluated within `foo_wrapper`.

```
> m <- list(1,2,3)
> foo(m)
[1] TRUE
> foo_wrapper(m)

 Error in FUN(X[[1L]], ...) : argument "arg" is missing, with no default
```

Now, I could use the `dots` arguments for this purpose, which would work.

```
foo_wrapper <- function(x, ...) {
  sapply(x, foo, ...)
}

> m <- list(1,2,3)
> foo(m)
[1] TRUE
> foo_wrapper(m)
[1] TRUE TRUE TRUE
```

Still, I would like to know if there is a way to include the `arg` argument in the wrapper function explicitly, not pass it via the `dots` argument.

Is there a way?

Comment: Unless you specifically don't want a default value, you could write `foo_wrapper<-function(x,arg=0)`

Comment: Or, to be exact,  `arg=TRUE` since that's the default in the inner function

Comment: The problem is that I want the same default values as the inner function and there is none :)

Comment: but you effectively have a default value by way of your `if(missing(arg)) arg<-TRUE` statement

Comment: For our example yes, but for the function I want to wrap, the default calculation is a quite difficult. Thus, I would have to replicate the calculation inside the wrapper, which would get a bit messy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could check for whether `arg` is missing before calling `sapply`:

```
foo_wrapper <- function(x, arg)
if(missing(arg)) sapply(x, foo) else sapply(x, foo, arg=arg)
```

but it's probably cleaner just to use `...`.

Comment: I find this is a nice idea! ... Unfortunately it is not feasible for me, as there are a couple of arguments that are allowed be missing. So this will quickly results in a fast growing number of possible call combinations and in somewhat messy code. Thanks for the idea!